# How can i make a lead conversion fail in test class

Tags: apex, trigger, developer

I have a trigger to convert Lead to Contact. For some reason it wasn't converting some automated incoming leads. To figure that out, I added Email Messaging so anytime it fails, it will send an error email to me. I am trying to move this to production, however, the test class shows 62% coverage. Apart from creating a validation rule on Contact and failing it, is there any other way in test class I can make the lead conversion fail to increase the code coverage?

Trigger :

```
trigger convertMarketoLeads on Lead (after insert) 
{
    // added by 501Partners to ensure only Marketo leads are auto-converted
    Id myId = [Select Id From User Where Username like 'abc@gmail.com%' limit 1].Id;
    list<String> errors = new list<String>();


    List<Database.LeadConvert> leadCollectionArray = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for(Lead l : trigger.new)
    {
        if(!l.isConverted && l.CreatedByID == myId)
        {
          Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
          lc.setLeadId(l.Id);
          lc.setConvertedStatus('Marketing Qualified Lead');
          lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
          leadCollectionArray.add(lc);
         }
    }   


    Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(leadCollectionArray,false);

    // set any created accounts to be 1:1 with their contacts
    List<Account> a = new List<Account>();
    integer resSize = lcr.size();
    for (integer j = 0; j < resSize; ++j) 
    {
        String error='';
        if (lcr[j].isSuccess()) 
        {
            Account tempa = new Account(id=lcr[j].getAccountId(), npe01__SYSTEMIsIndividual__c=TRUE, npe01__One2OneContact__c=lcr[j].getContactId());
            a.add(tempa);
        }

        else{

            error='Error(s) on lead with ID: ' + +lcr[j].getLeadId()+'\n';
            for(Database.Error err: lcr[j].getErrors()){
                error += 'Status Code: ' + err.getStatusCode() + '; Message: ' + err.getMessage() + '\n';
            }
            errors.add(error);
        }
    }
    update a;

    if(!errors.isEmpty()){

         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
         String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'xyz@berklee.edu'};
         mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
         mail.setReplyTo('xyz@berklee.edu');
         mail.setSenderDisplayName('Apex error message');
         mail.setSubject('Error from Org : ' + UserInfo.getOrganizationName());
         String errorBody = String.join(errors, '\n\n');
         mail.setPlainTextBody(errorBody);
         Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
private class testConvertMarketoLeads
{
    public static testMethod void testConvertMarketoLeads()
    {
       // Setup test data
      User Muser = [Select Id From User Where Username like 'abc@gmail.com%' limit 1];

      System.runAs(Muser) 
      {
        List<Lead> newLeads = new List<Lead>();

        for(integer i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            newLeads.add(new Lead(LastName='Fish' + i, Company='Test Lead'+i));
        }

        insert newLeads;


     //  List<Lead> validateConvertedLeads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE isConverted = TRUE];
    //   system.assertEquals(100,validateConvertedLeads.size());


      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the reasons why we're advised to create a "Trigger Handler" class. This allows us to test the logic independently of actually calling the trigger.

## Trigger

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert) {
  LeadTriggerHandler.run(Trigger.old, Trigger.new);
}
```

## Trigger Handler

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {
  // Dispatch method
  public static void run(Lead[] triggerOld, Lead[] triggerNew) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {

    } else { // Trigger.isAfter
      if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        afterInsert(triggerOld, triggerNew);
      }
    }
  }
  // DML event handlers
  @TestVisible static void afterInsert(Lead[] triggerOld, Lead[] triggerNew) {
    autoConvertLead(triggerNew);
  }
  // Utility methods
  static void autoConvertLead(Lead[] triggerNew) {
    // Logic to convert lead and email on failure
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: Different types of trigger handler frameworks are possible, this is only one of the many simpler types you can use to get started. You can read more about [frameworks](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) elsewhere if you're interested.

The main point here is that a handler class allows you to directly call a DML event to test it.

## Sample Test Method

```
@isTest static void testLeadConvertFail() {
  // Purposefully fail
  LeadTriggerHandler.afterInsert(new Lead[] { new Lead() }, new Lead[] { new Lead() });
  // Check to make sure an email was sent
  System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
}
```

This allows us to purposefully fail the test by passing in a lead without an ID value (because we did not actually insert a new record). The trigger itself is never called, but the logic we're interested in testing can be called directly.

Do make sure that you write a unit test that does test the trigger itself by performing an actual DML operation, but this test can simply be a "happy path" test to make sure that your records can save successfully without running in to governor limits, etc.